# Create plugin with 3rd party MIT license code

Tags: plugins, licensing

I have own WP plugin under GPL2 license as need for WP, but now I wanna add some 3rd party code for directory listing and this code is under MIT license. What I need to do, that make all right and use this code in my plugin?

Comment: This is a licensing question, not a WordPress question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can include Expat (MIT) licensed libraries in your GPL plugin. WordPress [plugin guidelines](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#1-plugins-must-be-compatible-with-the-gnu-general-public-license) states,

> Although any GPL-compatible license is acceptable, using the same license as WordPress — “GPLv2 or later” — is strongly recommended. All code, data, and images — anything stored in the plugin directory hosted on WordPress.org — must comply with the GPL or a GPL-Compatible license. Included third-party libraries, code, images, or otherwise, must be compatible.

Here is a list of [licenses compatible with GPL](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/license-list.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses).

Comment: One more question, in MIT license need write author name if you use his code. To where put this lines in WP plugin? On page in plugin where I am using his code or in readme?

Comment: if the library/code you are using is properly documented, its author should have some preamble in their code headers itself, hence you are not required to acknowledge/declare it.  However, it is common and useful practice to add an acknowledgement in the readme.txt file.